# Different notation when using integration by parts?

Tags: calculus, statistics

I am trying to evaluate three integrals and I found this solution, but it uses some notation I'm unfamiliar with. The first result I solved a little differently using integration by parts once and then you need to figure out $\int_0^{\infty}e^{-x^2 / \beta ^2}$. But I don't really understand the second two integrals (part b, different just by power of x) especially since I find the notation very confusing. In the second step, how he moves the dx inside and it turns into d, I have never seen that, could someone explain maybe with more intermediate steps? Also, in the next step, I don't understand what that $dx^2$ is. I can see this is just repeated integration by parts, but I cannot seem to figure this out. Thanks a lot!

Apparently, it won't let me post images, so here is the link:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8yyU.png